# Bootstrap 5: Close offcanvas Menu after click anchor links

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

It is about a project created with Bootstrap 5. The problem was that the offcanvas menu stayed open, by clicking an anchor link. To close the menu after click I use the following code for an onclick event:

```
function close_offcanvas() {
            var element1 = document.getElementById("eff_nav_toggler");
            element1.classList.remove("collapsed");
            var element2 = document.getElementById("navbarSupportedContent");
            element2.classList.remove("show");
            document.getElementById("eff_nav_toggler").setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
}
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white fixed-top eff-main-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo ROOT_DIR ; ?>/index.php">
            <img src="<?php echo ROOT_DIR ; ?>/assets/images/logo/logo-klein_170.jpg" alt="Logo" title="Logo">
        </a>
        <button 
            id="eff_nav_toggler"
            class="navbar-toggler"  
            type="button" 
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"  
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"   
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"  
            aria-expanded="false"  
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 w-100 ps-5">
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo ROOT_DIR ; ?>/index.php#link1" onclick="close_offcanvas()">Link 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo ROOT_DIR ; ?>/index.php#link2" onclick="close_offcanvas()">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


It is working fine. But I am not sure if this is the best solution. Any other ideas?

Thank you
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to do the hard things. bootstrap has **attribute** called

```
data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
```

Add this attribute to your anchor tag or li tag. it will close offcanvas on click

Comment: This required `data-bs-target` as well, and in my case it closes the menu *before* it follows the link, making it not useful in the scenario described.

Comment: One of the only downvotes I have ever made. This is so horribly wrong.

It is true that data-bs-dismiss exists. It exactly causes an achor tag to change behaviour, which is totally against the OP's meaning, and could confuse people who are not experienced with web debugging

You should edit this to be "wrong" in red letters imo

Comment: This question should not be labeled as answered as the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with some javascript by adding a click event to each link and calling the hide method. I added a check for minimum width so it stays open on desktop browsers:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menuitem').forEach(item => {
item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Check if the viewport width is less than 450px
    if (window.innerWidth < 450) {
        // Close the offcanvas menu
        var bsOffcanvas = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(document.getElementById('offcanvasMenu'));
        bsOffcanvas.hide();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue. Here is my approach:

```js
// Select all <a> elements inside the offcanvas
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#main-nav a');

// Function to close the offcanvas menu
function closeOffcanvas() {
  const offcanvas = document.querySelector('.offcanvas');
  const backdrop = document.querySelector('.offcanvas-backdrop');
  offcanvas.classList.remove('show');
  backdrop.classList.remove('show');
}

// Add a click event listener to each <a> element
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', closeOffcanvas);
});
```

This solution also hides the backdrop that remains visible when the offcanvas is closed.